# lwp useragent 504 gatway timeout

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using strawberry perl 5.22 and try to run the folllowing code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $response = $ua->get('https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/feeds/csv/');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

I get 504 gateway

but when try to fetch the link using the browser it works as expected ?
could someone help to solve this issue ?

1. I tried different links like http://google.com it works as expected
2. I tried to use `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0});`

I get the following error: `500 Can't connect to ... (bad hostname)`

Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: The site you mentioned is down at the moment. So you'll have to wait till it's up.

Answer (score -1):

This is a server side problem and you are only lucky if you could access the site with the browser. I get the same gateway timeout with a browser too.